# Change the output of the sage function latex() on a string

Tags: verbatim, expansion, sagetex

Currently if you run the sage command `latex('a string')` using sage (or sagetex) the latex output looks like: `\text{\texttt{a{ }string}}`. I would like to eliminate either of these (preferably the `\texttt` command) so that it would yield something that looks like `\text{a{ }string}` or, even better, `\text{a string}`. Unfortunately, the latex command seems to be defined in such a way that I can't seem to edit how it parses strings.

Currently I am using a latex package that seems to (among other things) make the `\text` command prevent expansion of the inner contents, much like a verbatim environment (I don't know if this is normal in latex as I never actually use the `\text{}` command myself), so with the way sage is outputting strings I am getting a whole bunch of `\texttt{a{ }string}` output to my document, rather than the intended `a string`.

Any suggestions on either a sage, or a latex fix for this? I would try to do some sort of forced expansion, but since everything is called via the `\sage` command, it isn't expandable, which leaves me unsure of what other avenues I could try to use to get this to work.

Thanks!

PS: Although you can use the commands mentioned above in a sage cell to get the results, here is a MWE, using the cls and packages I am using [here](https://github.com/XronosUF/Xronos-Latex-Package):

```
\documentclass{ximera}
\usepackage{PackageLoader}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
string = "a string"
\end{sagesilent}
$\sage{string}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have sage installed so I can't test it, but maybe `\sagestr` would be useful? According to the documentation '`\sagestr` is identical to `\sage`, but it does not run Sage's `latex` function on the code you give it; it simply runs the Sage code and pulls the result into your `\LTX` file'.

Comment: See also a usage example on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212792/how-to-store-values-in-variables-in-sagetex (at the end of the answer).

Comment: @Marijn anyone can test anything Sage and SageTeX with no install, using [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com).